# Changing App Store Login

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

We Have two Users on a 2013 MacBook Pro: 'A' and 'B'.
However, when User 'B' tries to log in to the App Store, the login prompt is already completed with User 'A' info.
Is it possible to have two Users log in separately to the App Store on one laptop?

Comment: 2 users on 2 separate Mac accounts? I just tested, autocomplete does not carry between [Mac] user accounts, so I'm guessing they both use the same one.

Comment: sign-in doesn't carry across either

Answer (score 3):

What you see as 'already completed with User A info' is the auto-complete feature. You can change user in the App Store following this:

1. Open the App Store app
2. MenuBar > Store > Sign Out...
3. MenuBar > Store > Sign In...
4. Delete info in Apple ID and Password fields
5. Enter User 'B' info and press Sign in

Comment: If this is just an automatic completion at work here, what might step 2 do?

Comment: @danielAzuelos I'm not sure I understand. User B is signing in (Step 5)?!

Comment: That it! It appears User 'B' hadn't completed all the details required by the App Store and once that was done, it was possible to sign 'A' out and 'B' in.